# iOS: "resizableImageWithCapInsets:" not stretching in tabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c

As suggested by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19850333/2561805), I'm using

```
self.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabBackground.png"] 

resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10) 

resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
```

for each selected tab bar item

For some reason, I'm getting white space on the edges. I'm assuming it's not stretching fully

Here's what I'm getting(screenshot):  [image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Check your image size if it is a retina image or not,then the  point size.**

The insets should be

```
UIEdgeInsetsMake(5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f) // as worked for me..
```

Comment: did u try? to add 2x2